# Unknown "delete" error in my C code

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, linked-list, free

For this code, I have to fill the functions from the function prototypes given to us by the teacher. For this specific function, I keep getting the  error below.

> "error: expected ';' before 'p'"
>             delete p;

```
int delete(struct node *start, int data){
     struct node *q, *p;
     int dataAfter;
     p = find(start, dataAfter);
     if (p != NULL){
         q = start;
         while (q->next != p){
             q = q->next;
         }
         q->next;     

         p->next;   

         delete p;    

         return 1;                 
     }
     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The `delete` keyword does not exist in C.

Comment: C does not have the `operator delete`. Use `free ()` in C.

Comment: Whats `q->next;` and `p->next;` supposed to do?

Comment: How would I be able to adjust this portion of my code to exclude delete. I am unsure as to how I can fix this error because this is actually the first time i've encountered this in c. Thank you.

Comment: If you meant `free(p)` please observe that `p->next` is not needed.

Comment: `dataAfter` is uninitialized, you are passing an uninitialized value to `find`. The `node` you get might not be even the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

The error itself is a syntax error - there aren't much code in C which looks like 'delete p'. Since 'delete' is not a predefined function in C(unlike 'return'. return 1 works just fine, though it looks somewhat like 'delete p'), it was regarded that a semi-colon would be needed after the 'delete'.

However, even if you *do* include the semi colon, it still wouldn't work for the reasons given by the earlier comments.

Replace 'delete' with 'free()' to remove the compile time error, but you would still need change

```
q->next;
p->next;
```

to

```
q->next = p->next;
```

for the linked list to be appropriately connected even after the deletion.

Linked list may be real confusing at first, so it is advised you always draw what you are trying to implement on a piece of paper next to your computer.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. 'delete' is not a predefined anything, while return is a predefined "statement". Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to delete a node from the linked list.  So, first find the right node and it's pointed to by p.  Then, make the previous node's next pointer skip p. To do that, change:

```
q->next;     
p->next;
```

to:

```
q->next = p->next;
```

Also, as other's point out, `delete` is not in C, it's in C++.  So, next make this change:

```
delete p;
```

to:

```
free(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I keep getting the error below. "error: expected ';' before 'p'

This error occurs because compiler expects you to finish the `statement` by using a semicolon `;`.
In your case your expression is a `name` of the function `delete` ! Compiler knows what the `delete` is.  Otherwise you would get different error.

This is illustrated in the comments by the following program:

```
/* $gcc -o main *.c -Wall -pedantic  -ansi */

#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
  int p;

  foo  p; /* error: expected ‘;’ before ‘p’ */
  foo; p; /* warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value] */

  fxx;    /* error: ‘fxx’ undeclared (first use in this function) */
  p;      /* warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value] */
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Your particular scenario is covered by `C` [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.3) dealing with `Expression and null statements`.

The logic of `int delete(struct node *start, int data)`  requires a lot of work.
None of the current responses address all the logic problems inside the `delete`.
All solutions would crash when `start == p`.

- Please note that `delete` is a name of the function used in C++. In C we use `free(...)` to release the allocated memory.
- `dataAfter` is an initialized integer. Quite likely you meant to use `data`.

Managing the linked list is not difficult but it requires attention to details.

- When you delete the node in the list you have a responsibility to connect the nodes.
- If you delete the head you have a responsibility to move the head.
- If the head is the node you are looking for and this is the only node in the list than after removal that node has to be marked as `NULL`.

Please take a look a complete `simple implementation` of the single linked list with the test program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

// Basic simple single list implementation to illustrate 
// proper deletion of the node 

// Node in List
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next; // pointer to next node
}node;

// List structure
typedef struct list {
    node* head;     // The entry point into a linked list.  If the list is empty then the head is a null reference. 
} list;

// Create list
list* list_create()
{
    list* new_list = malloc(sizeof(list));

    if(new_list == NULL)
        return NULL;        // protection

    new_list->head = NULL;  // If the list is empty then the head is a null reference.  no elements in the list 

    return new_list;        // return created new list
}

// returns newly created node
node* node_new(int data)
{
    node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node)); // allocate memory for the node 

    if (new_node == NULL)
        return NULL;                             // protection 

    new_node->data = data;                       // remember the data 
    new_node->next = NULL;                       // no next node

    return new_node;                             // return new created node
}

// The method creates a node and prepends it at the beginning of the list.
// 
// Frequently used names for this method:
// 
// insert at head
// add first
// prepend
//
// returns new head or NULL on failer

node* prepend_node(list* in_list, node* new_node)

{
   // Add item to the front of the in_list, return pointer to the prepended node (head)    

    if(in_list == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(new_node == NULL)                         // problem, not enough memory
       return NULL;                              // in_list->head has not changed 

/* 
                 new_node      
                   |*| -->  NULL   
                   next        
*/       
    if(in_list->head == NULL)                    // if list is empty 
    {
        in_list->head = new_node;                // the new_node becomes a head   
    }
    else // list already have a head node
    {
/*
                |2|-->|1|-->NULL
                 ^ 
                 |
                 *
                head (2) (list pointer)

*/
        new_node->next = in_list->head;     // now, the new node next pointer points to the node pointed by the list head, see below:       

/* 
          new_node     
            |3|-->     |2|-->|1|-->NULL
                        ^  
                        |
                        *
                       head (list pointer)
*/          
        in_list->head = new_node;               // the list head has to move to new_node ( a new prepanded node)  

 /* 
          new_node       
            |3|-->  |2|-->|1|-->NULL
             ^       
             |           
             *           
            head (3) (list pointer)
*/         
    }

    return in_list->head;                       // we are returning pinter to new_node
}

// Print out list
void print_list(list* in_list)
{
    node* node;

    if (in_list == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (in_list->head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty!\n");
        return;
    }

   printf("List: ");

   node = in_list->head;

    while(node != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %d", node->data);

        node = node->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

struct node *find(struct node *start, int data)             // find p to be removed
{
    node* node;

    if (start == NULL)
        return NULL;

    node = start;

    while(node != NULL)
    {
        if (node->data == data)
            return node; 

        node = node->next;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int delete(struct node *start, int data){
// This function will crash if start == p 
// Has other problems too  
// For better implementation see sg7_delete.  
     struct node *q, *p;

     p = find(start, data);
     if (p != NULL){
         q = start;
         while (q->next != p){
            q = q->next;
         }

         q->next = p->next;   
         free(p);    

         return 1;     
     }
     return 0; 
}

int sg7_delete(struct node **start, int data)
{
     struct node *p, *prev, *next, *to_free;

     if (start == NULL)                      // protection
        return 0;

     p = find(*start, data);                 // find p to be removed

     if (p == NULL)
        return 0;

     if (*start == NULL)
        return 0;                            // protection

     if(*start == p)                         // head == p
     {
        if((*start)->next !=NULL)
        {
            *start = (*start)->next;         // remember next 
            free(p);
            printf("Head removed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else // the only node
        {
            free(p);

            printf("Last node removed\n");
            *start = NULL;

            return 1;
        }
     }

     // p != start:

     next = *start; 

     while (next != NULL)
     {
        prev = next;                       
        to_free = next->next;                // candidate to be freed   

       if( to_free == p )
        {
            prev->next = to_free->next;      // connect nodes before deletion 

            free(to_free);                   // now free the remembered `next`
            to_free = NULL;                  // so it does not point to the released memory
            return 1;
        }

        next = next->next;                   // this node was not a match 
     } //while

    return 0; 
}

int main() {

   list* new_list = list_create();

   node *n1 = node_new(1);
   node *n2 = node_new(2);
   node *n3 = node_new(3);

  // list is empty
   print_list(new_list);

   prepend_node(new_list, n1);
   prepend_node(new_list, n2);
   prepend_node(new_list, n3);

  // list has 3 elements
   print_list(new_list);

   sg7_delete(&new_list->head, 3);  
   print_list(new_list);

   sg7_delete(&new_list->head, 1);  
   print_list(new_list);

   sg7_delete(&new_list->head, 2);
   // list has 2 elements
   print_list(new_list);

   printf("head: %p\n",new_list->head);

   print_list(new_list);

#if 0     
   // printf("TEST OF THE ORIGINAL FUNCTION\n");
   n1 = node_new(1);
   n2 = node_new(2);
   n3 = node_new(3);

   prepend_node(new_list, n1);
   prepend_node(new_list, n2);
   prepend_node(new_list, n3);

   print_list(new_list);

   delete(new_list->head, 1);   // REMOVE THE TAIL 

   print_list(new_list);

   //delete(new_list->head, 3); // WILL CRASH IF HEAD IS REMOVED - signal 11
   //delete(new_list->head, 2); // WILL CRASH IF HEAD IS REMOVED - signal 11
#endif

  free (new_list); // after deleting all elements, delete the list itself
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
List is empty!
List:  3 2 1
Head removed
List:  2 1
List:  2
Last node removed
List is empty!
head: (nil)
List is empty!
```